# Broken Gems while Upgrading

Tags: gruntjs, rubygems

I tried updating one of my gems and ran into a whole lot of issues. I installed RVM (osx) thinking it would cure some issues - it didnt.
When running my grunt command i get this as my output:

```
    Warning: Running "jekyll:server" (jekyll) task
`bundle exec jekyll build --source app --destination .jekyll --config _config.yml` was initiated.

Jekyll output:
Warning: Command failed: /Users/Amit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/commander-4.1.6/lib/commander/runner.rb:385:in `block in require_program': program version required (Commander::Runner::CommandError)
    from /Users/Amit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/commander-4.1.6/lib/commander/runner.rb:384:in `each'
    from /Users/Amit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/commander-4.1.6/lib/commander/runner.rb:384:in `require_program'
    from /Users/Amit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/commander-4.1.6/lib/commander/runner.rb:52:in `run!'
    from /Users/Amit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/commander-4.1.6/lib/commander/delegates.rb:8:in `run!'
    from /Users/Amit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/commander-4.1.6/lib/commander/import.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/Amit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/safe_yaml-0.9.7/lib/safe_yaml/syck_node_monkeypatch.rb:42:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Syck (NameError)
    from /Users/Amit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/safe_yaml-0.9.7/lib/safe_yaml.rb:200:in `require'
    from /Users/Amit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/safe_yaml-0.9.7/lib/safe_yaml.rb:200:in `<module:YAML>'
    from /Users/Amit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/safe_yaml-0.9.7/lib/safe_yaml.rb:132:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Amit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/jekyll-1.3.1/lib/jekyll.rb:21:in `require'
    from /Users/Amit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/jekyll-1.3.1/lib/jekyll.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Amit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/jekyll-1.3.1/bin/jekyll:7:in `require'
    from /Users/Amit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/jekyll-1.3.1/bin/jekyll:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Amit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    from /Users/Amit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/Amit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/Amit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
 Use --force to continue.
```

Can someone help me fix/resolve this? Should i start over again? My build was generated prior to installing RVM.

Answer (score 0):

I ran 'rvm reset and 'rvm version and it seems to have fixed my problem. Not too sure what was going on - I believe the ruby versions were confused.